# mvc dropdownlistfor validation run before submitting

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an `MVC 5 Application`. I have a View that inherits from a `Model View`. I have a `DropDownlistFor` with `Validation` that cannot be empty.

The problem I have is that Validation executes as soon as I select an item from `Dropdownlist`. When I select the same First item "Choose a Country", I mean, y select the same default option, validation execute and show a Message `"Country is required"`...

I put an alert on `jquery` `Submit` button and on `Controller Method` and it does not reach that point.

Another curious thing is that this App is a Migration from `Entity Framework` to `Enterprise Library Store Procedure` ..

The `Model` that inherits the `View` is loaded on the Controller from `Store Procedure` instead of `EntityFrawork`.

This should be transparent to the View. But this error happens only in this versión. It Works fine with `Entity Framework`.

Here is part of the code..

```html
@model AvivaVozSP.Models.UserViewModel
@using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax

 <form action="@Url.Action("Create", "Users")" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 
 <div class="DvCampoUp">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.user.Country_id, Model.AvailableCountries, new { @class = "StyleOb Required txtFill", @onclick = "ocultar();", @onchange = "javascript:GetState(this.value);", @id = "Country_id" })
 </div>
 <div class="DvCampoUp">
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Country_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>

</form>

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   $('form').submit(function (event) {
                alert(1);
 });
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: is "Choose a Country" part from the list? because you could use default value from  @Html.DropDownListFor()  parameter

Comment: Yes, Choose a Country is ítem(0) from the list... I open the dropdownlist and do not choose any country, the validation runs. My question es why validation runs if I do not submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the default value like this

```c#
 <div class="DvCampoUp">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.user.Country_id, Model.AvailableCountries,"Choose a Country", new { @class = "StyleOb Required txtFill", @onclick = "ocultar();", @onchange = "javascript:GetState(this.value);", @id = "Country_id" })
 </div>
```

and remove `Choose a Country` from the list

Comment: It Works... but still I do not understand what is does not work. Maybe I am loosing a reference... In fact, I have another error that is happening with this versión, I am posting soon. Thanks